# gmp_int Boost errors

Tags: c++, boost, codeblocks, gmp

Here is my simple test code:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int main()
{
    gmp_int v = 1;
    std::cout << v << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to build and run, I get the following errors:

```
error: there are no arguments to 'mp_get_memory_functions' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'mp_get_memory_functions' must be available [-fpermissive]
note: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
error: 'mp_get_memory_functions' was not declared in this scope
error: 'mpz_combit' was not declared in this scope
error: 'mp_get_memory_functions' was not declared in this scope|
error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const __mpz_struct*' [-fpermissive]
error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_int]'
```

I am using Code::Blocks. I used precompiled GMP libraries for windows. In code::Blocks I have `gmp\lib\libgmp.a`in the linker, `gmp\include` in compiler directories and `gmp\lib` in linker directories. 
Any help would be appreciated in getting GMP to work. I think that I did not install GMP correctly, but it might be a simple issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I was not linking all my header and library files correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to use a number adaptor with your `gmp_int` backend type:

```
number<gmp_int> v = 1;
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b82c2a92d06a4bbe)**:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int main()
{
    number<gmp_int> v = 1;
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same errors. Does GMP have to be installed for Boost's gmp_int to work?

Comment: Yes it does. I must admit your installation seems broken if the above sample doesn't compile. (As you can see, it does on Coliru)

Comment: I am using GMP 4.1 library and header files, do you think this is outdated?

Comment: @qwr Yes, 4.1 is outdated. Note that editing your question with "fixed" is not the SO policy, instead you should post an answer explaining exactly what you did to solve the issue. I assume you simply upgraded the library to 4.2 or later.